# how do i navigate away from an angular app

Tags: angularjs

so i have an angular app with custom routing set up.

all `<a>` links outside any angular scope with `$route` (in my case, the only scope is the `ng-view`) navigate like normal (ie. standard location change and page reload, as if angular didn't exist)

all links inside inside an angular scope with $route (ie. my `ng-view`) get routed through angular's `$routeProvider` - they are given a template and controller.

**my question**

how do i make an `<a>` link inside my `ng-view` navigate away from the angular app, to a different, static, non-angular location in the site?

Comment: if the route is not handled by angular router there should be no problem navigating to another webpage. that's why it's a good idea to namespace routes in angular. Or you can have your controller redirect to a different location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use

```
<a target="_self" href="url">
```

Comment: doh.. talk about trying to overthink a solution to this one :( thanks for the help.